# EventStore in Docker

Tags: docker

I am busy investigating the use of Docker for a system that I am working on. We use EventStore and I was quite happy to see that there is a [Docker container](https://github.com/EventStore/eventstore-docker) for it already.

But when I was looking through it, I saw this posted multiple times.

> Note: This container is for development purposes only

I am trying to find out what makes this container unsuitable for production but cant seem to find a straight answer from anyone. The closest that I have gotten is that all the ES nodes will be in the same container, so if it goes down, everything goes down.

There is also this [thread](https://github.com/EventStore/eventstore-docker/issues/7).

So can someone please give me a concise reason as to why ES is not suited with Docker in a production environment?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on [Event Store](https://geteventstore.com/). There might be features specific to Event Store that make it less suitable to run from a container which I am not aware off.

In general, you can 'dockerise' most services and they can perform equally well as a service that is run natively on a server.

The things to be aware off are:

- where do you keep your data
- where do you keep your configuration files
- what performance is required
- what about safety

**Data**: Because of the way the container is run in the example, your data will be 'inside' the container. Delete or upgrade the container and your data is gone forever.

To make your data persistent use [data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) or [data volume containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container). These keep your data on the host (their Dockerfile already has support for it, see `VOLUME`).

There are also storage solutions that allow you to access data remotely using [volume plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/).

**Configuration Files**: Same story as for your data. You can keep your configuration file(s) in a data volume (container) or pass them via the Dockerfile (as they've done in their Dockerfile).

**Performance**: There can be a slight performance hit in some situations when using Docker versus native. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21889053/4459346

**Safety**: Because of the way the container is run in the example, the Event Store will be exposed on the host machine. Anyone can access them externally. To keep them local to the host use `-p 127.0.0.1:1113:1113`.

At the company I work for I have set up a `mysql` server in a container. The data and configuration files are 'stored' in a data volume container. I also have set up a cron job that runs another container to back up the `mysql` data to the host.

A number of applications (also 'dockerised') are happily using `mysql` that way. We haven't seen any difference with running `mysql` natively. There can be 50+ users at a time.